# how i can make a function that they update the content when user on the bottom of page ? jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

Like google reader and many other applicaton i want to make a function who update the page using ajax request.

means when user on the bottom of page then i send the request and append response to the exisitng content of page.

how i can do that in jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is "infinite scrolling".

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/